# How to discard the changes I don't commit?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I don't know what happened but I messed up the Git repo again. So all was OK , it was compiling fine. Not compiling now. I had made some changes, not committed any. When I do repo diff I see the changes I made and some weird changes have come into the code. I don't know! Lot of them. So now I think inorder to fix this and keep the changes I deliberately made and the changes that appear from no where. I will do git add the changes I made and I want to discard all the changes that otherwise appear. How to do this ?

```
git add filepath
```

And how to discard what I don't want to add and commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following steps:

1. Use `git add` to add the changes you want to keep.
2. `git commit` those changes to the repository.
3. `git reset --hard HEAD` to throw away the rest of the changes.

Note that step 3 is *destructive* and you can't use Git to recover those changes. Make a backup first if you're unsure.

Comment: Hi , I think I must have done something like git checkout remotes/somebranch.I tried doing git checkout mywork to get back from this . Any help with this plz.

Comment: The `git checkout` command switches branches. Try `git checkout master` (the name `master` is the default main branch name).

Comment: This I already tried . fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Comment: Well, that means you're not inside a Git repository at all. I would check your current directory and make sure you are where you think you are.

Comment: hi I am using a repo so things are quite different here, I do repo stage -i into the project files that have changed . Then I have a add untracked option I choose that for each individual change and then update option in here. Problem is when I do repo diff I still see those files that I changed I dont know where my previous steps like add untracked and update have taken effect. Thanks for yr all help.

Comment: Ah, sorry I don't use repo so I'm afraid I can't really help you there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GitHub GUI (Windows or Mac) and are not worried about losing the local changes on your computer but just need to get the latest version from GitHub:

Simply use "discard changes" before attempting to sync. This can be done either for a specific file:

[image]

or for all files:

[image]

It reverts all selected files to the last version committed to the repo.